# remove embedded media

Tags: wygwam

Testing Wygwam 2.7 with a Youtube video uploaded via the Embed Media button, but the embed needs to be removed when an excerpt of the entry appears on the home page. Can this be done with Wygwam natively?

Comment: Yes, most likely, but we need more info to help you. Did you create a separate excerpt field (separate from the Wygwam field)? What's your current template code look like? What's the Wygwam field name?

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing. [From the docs](http://pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/docs/templates):

```
{wygwam_field text_only="yes"}
```

This will strip all other HTML as well, but for an excerpt that's probably desirable anyway.